# Find angle of conical pendulum with only period and string length

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

I have a lab for Physics which asks to find the angle $θ$ given the period and string length of a conical pendulum. We were tasked to construct one of these with a piece of string ranging from $0.4m$ to $0.8m$  with an object tied to the end (mass does not matter so we were not instructed to weigh the item on the end of the string). The conical pendulum I made had a string length of $0.44 m$ and had a period of around $1.44 seconds$ (14.40 seconds for 10 full spins). The thing is, I'm stumped on how to find the angle with just those two pieces of information.

[image]

I realize that finding the radius of the pendulum, plugging that radius into a triangle diagram of the pendulum and then using sin law to find $θ$ is a way I can do this, however, with the equations I've seen I don't know how to find the radius with *only* the period and length. I have attempted to rearrange and combine formulas in an attempt to figure out the radius with the information I know,but to no avail. Any suggestion or hint pointing me in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should start with a free body diagram showing the forces acting on the weight. The period indicates the centripetal acceleration which leads to the radial force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've studied simple harmonic motions (SHMs), you can prove that the time period of a simple pendulum is given by:

$$T=2\pi {\sqrt  {{\frac  {L \cos \theta}{g}}}}$$

Since all these values are known to you ($T$ and $L$), you can find $\theta$.
This result can also be proved by using dynamics and kinematics ($v=\frac {2\pi R}{T}$) along with the equations of components of the tension along the vertical and the radius ($T\cos\theta=mg$ and $T\sin\theta=\frac {mv^2}{R}$).

Usually in phyisics, however, we assume that the angle $\theta$ is small. Then, by the small angle approximation, we know that for small values of $\theta$, $\cos \theta \approx 1$. Then,

$$T\approx2\pi {\sqrt  {{\frac  {L}{g}}}}$$

This means the period isn't dependent on the angle $\theta$ for small values of theta. Note that  this is also equal to the time period of a simple pendulum (simple harmonic oscillator) for small amplitudes.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to do, thank you very much!